# How to format bar chart yearly x-axis to not contain floats

Tags: python, bar-chart, plotly-python, xticks, stacked-bar-chart

What causes the x-axis to have  Year numbers in between the  bars and the 0.5 attached to the Population Year

```
ru = px.bar(wakel, x = "Population Year", y = "Population", color = "City")
ru.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this behaviour (and rather than having to modify your data beforehand) you can tell plotly to treat the x axis values as 'categorical' by updating the layout for the x axes.

```
ru.update_xaxes(type='category')
```